# Watching older Youtube Live Streams

Tags: youtube, youtube-live

I just noticed the following Youtube livestream:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPfHHls50-w

which is of a Falcon Heavy launch which happened 9 days ago. Despite that, it still is marked as LIVE and I cannot jump forward in it. There are also people posting comments with timestamps which are in realtime now. I thought that usually livestreams turned into normal Youtube videos after they completed but this is not a normal video.

Am I watching an old livestream from 9 days ago which is somehow "repeating" or is this "false advertising" and claims to be live now but is actually re-streaming the previous event as if it were happening now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The link you've provided is for a YouTube network that replays launches and other space related events (it appears with permission). The official video of the launch can be found on SpaceX's YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXMGu2d8c8g

Comment: Thank you for the clarification but I still don't understand the way the stream works. It would not allow me to fast-forward, and closing and re-opening the stream did not start from the beginning, so it seems that this was being treated as a "live" stream but being sourced from a recording. What is the purpose of that? Why not just make it a regular video?

Comment: I guess rebroadcasting the stream gives them an opportunity to collect ad revenue, especially from those who don't realise it isn't live. For users they can participate in the real time chat with others watching the same thing, which makes it a bit more interesting.